# Problems using StreamPlot. Can't label stream plot axes and increase stream density

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would like to create a plot in Mathematica similar to

[image: example plot]

for the equation $\frac{d P}{dt}=P(0.6-0.003P).$

My attempt so far is

```
StreamPlot[{1, P (0.6 - 0.003 P)}, {t, 0, 30}, {P, 0, 220}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, StreamPoints -> {Automatic, 0.1}, 
 StreamScale -> None, StreamStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 220}}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "P(t)"}]
```

[image: best so far]

My questions are

- Why don't the Axes labels appear on the image?
- How can I increase the density of the stream points?
- Can I increase the thickness of the lines?
- How can I change the colour of the lines to black?
- Some stream points appear and disappear how can I get rid of these odd looking points?

Comment: Use `StreamStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Black, Dashed}`; and `FrameLabel` instead of `AxesLabel`.

Comment: Do you know how I can increase the density of stream points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example graphic, I think you want `VectorPlot` rather than `StreamPlot`.  Use `VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0]` to eliminate the arrowheads, if that's what you want.

```
VectorPlot[{1, P (0.6 - 0.003 P)}, {t, 0, 30}, {P, 0, 220}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 220}}, Axes -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t", "P(t)"}, 
     VectorStyle -> {Thick, Black, Arrowheads[0]}]
```

[image]